# (PHP 5.1.6) Fatal error: Class 'DateTimeZone' not found

Tags: php

How can i run this code on PHP 5.1.6

`$tz = new DateTimeZone($obj['timezone']);`

without upgrading my PHP version?

or is there any alternative?

I'am getting this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DateTimeZone' not found

Thank you

Comment: Its not supported in version 5.1.6 but supported in (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7)

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568992/php-5-3-fatal-error-class-datetimezone-not-found

Comment: Only: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: WHY are you running 5.1? Can I please know the URL where you're hosting this as I can imagine that there's a good amount of nice and abusive security flaws in a product that **stopped security updates more than 10 years ago** (*24 August 2006*)? [On the bright side there's "only" 118 vunerabilities and 12 exploits](http://www.cvedetails.com/version/36749/PHP-PHP-5.1.6.html)

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.1.x has only experimental support for DateTime

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php

> Note: Experimental DateTime support in PHP 5.1.x
>
> Although the DateTime class (and related functions) are enabled by
>   default since PHP 5.2.0, it is possible to add experimental support
>   into PHP 5.1.x by using the following flag before configure/compile:
>   CFLAGS=-DEXPERIMENTAL_DATE_SUPPORT=1

Answer (score 0):

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');   //set your timezone

$tz = date_default_timezone_get();   //display timezone

$date = date('Y:m:d');   //display date